# вывод следующего символа после найденого

Tags: c++, строки

Дана строка "Item is in my hand."

```
string.fing("m"); // позиция m нормально.
```

как вывести следующий символ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string f("Item is in my hand.");
    int tmp = f.find("m",5);
    string res = f.substr(tmp);
    cout << res[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Предполагаю что надо взять оставшуюся подстроку и вывести соотвественно второй символ с индексом 1. Есть способ легче?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это проще или нет?

```
int main()
{
    string f("Item is in my hand.");


    size_t tmp = f.find('m',5);
    if (tmp != string::npos)
        cout << f[tmp+1] << endl;

    auto it = find(begin(f)+5,end(f),'m');
    if (it != end(f))
        cout << *(++it) << endl;
}
```

Ну, или для C++17

```
if (size_t tmp = f.find('m',5); tmp != string::npos)
    cout << f[tmp+1] << endl;

if (auto it = find(begin(f)+5,end(f),'m'); it != end(f))
    cout << *(++it) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно же просто

```
string f("Item is in my hand.");                                            
cout <<  f[1 + f.find("m",5)] << endl;
```

Comment: А если символа `m` там нет? ))